# Self signed certificate error while connecting to WebSocket in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift

I am having trouble with self signed certificates using WebSockets in WKWebView. I keep getting the following error and am unsure how to go about it:

```
WebSocket network error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -9807.)
```

As a temporary fix I am trying to allow unverified ssl certificates by implementing this delegate function in my WKWebView:

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge,
    completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {
        let cred = NSURLCredential.init(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
        completionHandler(.UseCredential, cred)
}
```

This code allows me to bypass the SSL errors to load the page, but the WebSocket connection is still having errors... Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Any news on this? I am in the same situation...

Comment: I am also experiencing the same problem. Any solutions yet?

Comment: Almost a year later. Same problem. Any work around?

Comment: I've switched to using native websockets on mobile devices. Doesn't seem to be a browser compatible way.